# Excel VBA navigation of html elements

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am working on a code that uses VBA-excel to navigate to a website. Once I have logged into the website, I am not able to interact with any of the html elements within the page. I need to be able to click on some check boxes and enter a date range into a field.  Here is the code that I have. It works when I open a new window but I cant get it to work within the original ie window. I would like this process to be done in one window if possible. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim yesterday As String
yesterday = Date - 1
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim nik As Integer

'Opens Internet Explorer
Dim Shellwins As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Dim Shellie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set Shellwins = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Dim ie1 As InternetExplorer


Strurl = "father.com"
Set ie1 = New InternetExplorer
ie1.Visible = True
ie1.navigate Strurl
Do While ie1.readyState <> 4 And ie1.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Set htmldoc = ie1.document

For Each htmlel In htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
'MsgBox htmlel.Name
    If htmlel.ID = "ctl00_Body_txtEmailAddress" Then
        htmlel.Value = "dad@dad.com"
    End If
Next

Set htmldoc = ie1.document
For Each htmlel In htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    'MsgBox htmlel.Name
    If htmlel.ID = "ctl00_Body_txtPassword" Then
        htmlel.Value = "mom"
    End If
Next

Set htmldoc = ie1.document
For Each htmlel In htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If htmlel.ID = "ctl00_Body_btnLogon" Then
        htmlel.Click
    End If
Next

Strurl = "url.com"

Set ie2 = New InternetExplorer
ie2.Visible = True
ie2.navigate Strurl

ie1.Quit

Do While ie2.readyState <> 4 And ie2.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop
Set htmldoc = ie2.document
For Each htmlel In htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("input")

    If htmlel.ID = "ctl00_Body_txtStartDate" Then
        htmlel.Value = yesterday
    End If
Next

Set htmldoc = ie2.document
For Each htmlel In htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If htmlel.ID = "ctl00_Body_txtEndDate" Then
        htmlel.Value = yesterday
    End If
Next
```